# Can't get Flexdashoard valueBox running with Visual Studio 2017

Tags: r, visual-studio, r-markdown, flexdashboard

I'm using the R language along with Visual Studio 2017. I am trying to create a dashboard for my R scripts using Flexdashboard http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/flexdashboard/index.html

Just to get started I would like to create a valueBox and display today's date inside it. This is my .rmd file

````
---
title: "Dashboard v1"
output: flexdashboard::flex_dashboard
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
library(flexdashboard)

```

### Todays Date

```{r}
today <- Sys.Date()
valueBox(today, icon = "lock")

```
````

When I run the file inside Visual Studio 2017 the value box does not show, only the date. Please see screenshot below.

[image]

I'd appreciate any help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I think box objects like "valueBox" and "infoBox" ... are shinydashboard functions and use the shinyboard css and javascript to display the boxes.

This was a way I found to run the boxes inside Rmarkdown, by inserting a shinydashboard app inside the chunk:

````
---
title: "Dashboard v1"
output: flexdashboard::flex_dashboard
runtime: shiny
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
library(flexdashboard)

```

```{r}
library(shinydashboard)
today <- Sys.Date()

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(disable = TRUE),
  dashboardSidebar(disable = TRUE),
  dashboardBody(
    fluidRow(
      # A static valueBox
      valueBox(today, "New Orders", icon = icon("credit-card")),

      # Dynamic valueBoxes
      valueBoxOutput("progressBox"),

      valueBoxOutput("approvalBox")
    )
  )
 )

 server <- function(input, output) {
   output$progressBox <- renderValueBox({
    valueBox(
      paste0(25 + input$count, "%"), "Progress", icon = icon("list"),
      color = "purple"
    )
  })

  output$approvalBox <- renderValueBox({
    valueBox(
      "80%", "Approval", icon = icon("thumbs-up", lib = "glyphicon"),
      color = "yellow"
    )
  })
 }

shinyApp(ui, server)
```
````